# Why can't my Angular app load angular-route when I use RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

[My error is here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24injector%3anomod%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/%24injector/nomod?p0=app%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20%28nati)

All scripts have shown to be loaded in the Chrome dev tools Network tab, and here is my code:

*html:*

```
<script src='bower_components/requirejs/require.js' data-main="js/main"></script>

<script>
require(['app']);
</script>
```

*app.js:*

```
define(['angular-route','angular-sanitize'],function(){

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']); 

//...

return app;

});
```

Comment: So you're 100% sure a separate script for ng-route was loaded? As the page you linked says, it is now in a separate file that needs to be loaded along with Angular.

Comment: In chrome network I see it

Comment: Before I integrated my app with requirejs , it runs correctly

Comment: Posting the RequireJS configuration file may help.